# Gulp - output files not created

Tags: javascript, gulp

Below is a gulp task that has been created to compile angular2 tests written in typescript.

```js
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var typescript = require('typescript');

var tsTestProject = $.typescript.createProject({
  target: 'es5',
  sortOutput: true,
  typescript: typescript,
  experimentalDecorators: true
});

gulp.task('scripts-test', [], function () {
  var gulpStream = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/references.test.ts'),
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.spec.ts')
  ])
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe($.typescript(tsTestProject)).on('error', conf.errorHandler('TypeScript'))
  .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('tmptest'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
  .pipe($.size());
  
  return gulpStream;
});
```

Here's the log related to the task.

```
[20:47:45] Starting 'scripts-test'...
[20:50:18] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[20:50:18] Finished 'scripts-test' after 2.53 min
```

Yet no output files (typescripts compiled into js) are created to a tmptest folder as given in the task. `gulp-debug` shows that all the files given in `gulp.src` are acquired to the stream. Any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Does your error handler have a `this.emit('end')`

Comment: It does. But when I debugged using node-inspector, it proceeds to the .pipe($.sourcemaps.write()) line. Even the log says that the compilation was successful. The errors occur in some files that I'm not currently using.

Comment: I see that typescript is emitting errors so I'm just wondering if that error handler is catching an error and returning nothing on the stream.
I like to use `gulp-plumber` to handle all my errors and the same error handler that looks something like this `function(err) {
  console.log(err.toString());
  return this.emit('end');
};`
You will then probably see what line is emitting an error.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this was the issue... the task worked after I rectified the typescript issues.